# click event didn't work in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

```
define(["jquery" ,
"underscore" ,
"backbone" ,
"custom",
"wishlist"
],function($ , _ , Backbone, Ice, WishList){
var wishlist1 = new WishList();
var SavedCartView = Backbone.View.extend({
   tagName:"div",
   initialize : function(){
        console.log("hi!");
   },
   event : {
        'click .savedCart' : 'viewEachCart'
   },
   viewEachCart : function(e){
       console.log(1);
   },
   render : function(){
        wishlist1.viewAllSaveCart(106,function(output){
            _.each(output,function(row){
                $("#webbodycontainer").append('<a class="savedCart" id="'+row.ID+'">'+row.Name + "</a><br>");
            });
        });
   }
});
return SavedCartView;
});
```

Here is the router :

```
app_router.on('route:savedCart', function( ){
    if(window.currentSection)
        window.currentSection.remove(); 
    window.currentSection = new SavedCart({});

    $("#webbodycontainer").html(window.currentSection.$el);
    window.currentSection.render();
});
```

`console.log(1);` didn't work, Any idea what could be causing this. Thanks.

Comment: if you don't have `.saveCart` in DOM your render doesn't works correctly

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich : I have no idea how to place it in to the DOM.

Comment: what is WishList? i don't see it defined in the first parameter... include it with the other libraries

Comment: code which is inside render in not understandable, can you change your code, or try explain us

Comment: @Rohit : My bad typo, I edited it in the question.

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich : `wishlist1` is an instance of `WishList` class, then I use it to call for a method : `viewAllSaveCart(id,callbackfunction)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be `events : {`

Comment: Did exist `.savedCart` in the DOM when this view module is called?

Comment: Didn't find `.savedCart` in DOM of firebug.

Comment: But <a> contains value, why `.savedCart` did not exist in DOM

Comment: try to add an element with class 'savedCart' and u'll see your viewEachCart function working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41464/discussion-between-ilpaijin-and-domo)

Answer (score 0):

If ".savedCart" is an anchor tag (like this):

```
<a href="" class="savedCart">Saved Cart</a>
```

...then you need to have e.preventDefault() in your function so that the link is not activated.

```
   events : {
        'click a.savedCart' : 'viewEachCart'
   },
   viewEachCart : function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log(1);
   },
```